# useQuery isn't rendering/fetching multiple times on the local machine, but in production, it's working

Tags: reactjs, local, production-environment

When I run my react-project on my local machine, useQuery doesn't fetch data multiple-time, it renders data only on first-time loading.

```
const [todayAttendance, setTodayAttendance] = React.useState([]);

 const {
   data: allAttendance,
   isLoading: attendanceIsLoading,
   isError: attendanceIsError,
    } = useQuery(
   ["todaysAbsent", branchId],
     async () =>
      myAxios(`/all_attendance/${moment().format("MM")}/${moment().format(
      "YYYY"
    )}/?branch_id=${branchId ?? ""}`
  ),
{
  onSuccess: (e) => {
    setTodayAttendance([]);
    Object.values(e.data).filter(
      ({ attendance, name, position, information_user }, i) =>
        setTodayAttendance((prev) => [
          ...prev,
          {
            attendance: attendance[`${moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")}`],
            id: i,
            status:
              attendance[`${moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")}`]["status"],
            name: name,
            position: position,
            information_user: information_user,
          },
        ])
    );
  },
}
```

Comment: It's react query natural behavior that if the data does not change so use the cached data. If you wanna call the api on every refresh you should add a key to your useQuery to understand it that it should be re-render